# k-differentials and their residues

Tags: complex-geometry

I posted a question earlier. This question is smaller, more to the point and more basic I hope. Yet it is at the heart of my problems, I think.

In one of my references, degree k meromorphic differentials with poles of order $k$ at $n$ points $z_i$ on the Riemann sphere are mentioned: $\phi_k(z)=F(z)dz^k$. Here $F(z)$ is a rational function on the complex plane.

If we want to know the behaviour of $\phi_k(z)$ at $\infty$ we change coordinates to $z'=1/z$ under which the k-differential transforms as $\phi_k(z')=F(1/z')(-dz'/(z')^2)^k$. Furthermore, these k-differentials are required to have fixed residues $\alpha_i$ on each $z_i$.

Then it is stated that we thus allow: $$\phi_k(z) \sim \frac{\alpha_i}{(z-z_i)^k} dz^k +... $$

I have two questions about this:

1) May I also think of these k-differentials as $$\phi_k(z)=\frac{\prod^m_{i=1}c(z-u_i)}{\prod^n_{i=1}(z-z_i)^k}dz^k$$ Here, $c$ is a constant, $m=n-2$ in order that the degree of the divisor of this k-differential is $-2k$ as required on a Riemann surface of genus $g=0$. Furthermore, some of the $u_i$ and/or $c$ may depend on the fixed residues $\alpha_i$. If this is wrong, what is meant by the above stated form of the k-differential?

2) What does it mean for a k-differential to have a residue? For instance, how does Cauchy's formula work for a quadratic differential? Does a second order pole behave for a quadratic differential as a simple pole behaves for a 1-differential? If so, I don't think the residues of a quadratic differential sum to zero.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning  of *residue* in this context is that this quantity is a conformal invariant - and  even a formal invariant - and  furthermore  the unique such invariant. All this is to say that any k-differential with a pole of order (at worst) k can be expressed a scalar multiple of the standard differential, meaning $c\cdot\frac{dz^k}{z^k}$,  in an appropriate coordinate $z$.  This much works the same way for any  $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  For  $k=1$ the  residue has an additivity property which allows  for a global residue theorem,  but this won't be the case more generally: for  example, $\frac{dz^2}{z^2}$ has precisely two poles of equal nonzero residue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For 3 or more second order poles of a quadratic residue, $\frac{c(z-u_1)(z-u_2)}{(z-z_1)^2(z-z_2)^2(z-z_3)^2}dz^2$, there do not seem to be any relations anymore between the residues at the separate points $z_i$. Does this mean that when we fix the residues of a quadratic differential, we lose one more freely chooseable zero than in the case with a 1-differential (from which the residues do sum to zero and therefore we have one less constraint)?

Comment: I am asking about these 'free parameters' or freely chooseable zeroes because in the end I need to check that a certain one form, $\lambda = xdz$ with $x=\frac{G(F_1(z),F_2(z),...,F_k(z)))}{\prod (z-z_i)}$, differentiated wrt to one of the moduli is a holomorphic one-form on a curve defined by: $$x^k+F_1(z)x^{k-1}+...+F_k(z)=0$$. Hence, I want some sort of feeling or better yet concrete vision of how the $F_i$ depend on their moduli (and ofcourse how many moduli there are for given k and n).

Comment: I'n not entirely sure what you are asking. But, for example, if you specify a finite set of $n\geq 2$  points then there will exists a quadratic differential which has a double pole with 'residue' 1 at each of those points, and which is holomorphic elsewhere. You can write down such a quadratic differential as a sum of Mbbius translates of $\frac{dz^2}{z^2}$,at least for $n$ even, and a modified recipe works for $n$ odd. Moreover, the space of such quadratic differentials will  have dimension $\max(n-3,0)$.

Comment: I don't really see why this space is n-3-dimensional. Doesn't there exist a quadratic differential for $n=2$ right? This would be the one you've mentioned, $dz^2/z^2$ which has a double pole at $z=0$ and a double pole at $z=\infty$. If not, could you explain for $n=4,5$ what would be the beasis vectors of the space?

Comment: By the way, Adam, isn't the dimension of quadratic differentials with simple poles equal to $n-3$. Does this also hold for quadratics with double poles?

Comment: The space is  an $n-3$ dimensional hyperplane (but not a linear space)  precisely because the difference between  any pair of elements is   a quadratic differential  with at  worst simple poles. Regardinng existence, for $\alpha,\beta\in\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ let $q_{\alpha,\beta}$ be the unique quadratic differential having double poles with  residue 1 at  $\alpha$  and $\beta$,  that is,  $q_{\alpha,\beta}=\left(\frac{(\alpha-\beta)dz}{(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)}\right)^2$. Then  for any finite  set  $S$ consider $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{(\alpha,\beta)\in S\times S} q_{\alpha,\beta}$.

Comment: ...Then for any set $S$ with cardinality $n$, consider $\frac{1}{n(n−1)}∑_{(α,β)∈S×S}q_{α,β}$.

Comment: The normalizing constant should be $\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Comment: Shouldn't the normalization be $\frac{1}{2(n-1)}$? What do you precisely mean with the sum of the $q_{\alpha ,\beta}$'s?
For instance, would for $n=4$ $q_{\alpha ,\beta}-q_{\gamma ,\delta}$ be the 1 linearly independent vector in the hyperplane? Similarly, for $n=6$ ${q_{1,2}-q_{3,4},q_{1,2}-q_{5,6},q_{5,6}-q_{3,4}}$?

Comment: For each $\alpha$ there are  $n-1$ different  $q_{\alpha,\beta}$  each contributing residue 1.  The expressions you give yield quadratic differentials with some negative residues.

Comment: My factor of two comes from the fact that $q_{\alpha ,\beta}=q_{\beta ,\alpha}$. 
I  am still not sure what you mean by the sum. It gives a big quadratic differential with double poles at n-points and some complicated polynomial in the numerator, however with no zeroes at one of the n points, I think.

Comment: I have lost track of what you  were asking for. I was trying to give an example  of a quadratic differential with all  residues equal to 1. I do not attempt to simultaneously control the zeros.

Comment: All right thanks a lot for your help, I'll maybe post i new question about the subject. Anyhow, your answers helped me

Comment: Still I would very much appreciate if you could somehow explain why this space is n+3 dimensional. You state that this is because the difference between any pair of elements has at most a simple pole. Could you elaborate on this? For instance, are the elements you mean the $q_{\alpha ,\beta}$'s? Their differences do have poles of order two.

Comment: If two quadratic  differentials have double poles at $\zeta$, and  if the  residues at $\zeta$ are the same, then the difference has at worst a simple pole at $\zeta$.

Comment: Can you explain 'formal invariant', please? or Tell me some resource I can refer to.

Comment: That coefficient will survive unchanged when the expression of the $k$-differential is transformed by a local holomorphic change of coordinate. See the discussion of "natural parameters" in Strebel's book "Quadatic Differentials"